# Loop through JSON object containing array containing objects containing arrays containing etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm making an API call that returns a large tree of JSON data. It's structured like this:

```
{
...
children: [ {
             ... children: [ ... ], ...
            }, ... (10 or more objects) ]
...
}
```

Eventually (it's very large!) the `children` array will contain objects without a `children` array. I need to loop through the whole object and get all the elements that have property `content-kind: "Video"`; if it has a `content-kind` property it is guaranteed not to have a `children` array.

Sometimes what might happen is this:

```
children: [{ content-kind: "Video" }, { children: [ ... ] }, ...]
```

I want to grab the object with the `content-kind: "Video"` but still search the one with the `children` array.

I've tried every combination of while and for loops I could think of, but I couldn't solve my problem.

---

EDIT: Best attempt:

```
var e = json.children;
while (e.children) { e = e[0].children; }
if (e.content_kind == "Video") return e;
```

Obviously this won't work.

Comment: Try recursive function.

Comment: How would I write a recursive function to do that?

Comment: Would be good if you posted your best attempt.

Comment: "To learn about recursion, look up recursion"

Comment: I love how I see this question every week

Comment: I put in my best attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To traverse the tree and call `handle_node()` for every node, the recursion would be

```
function traverse(node) {
  if(node.children) node.children.forEach(traverse);
  handle_node(node);
}
```

Read more about [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: I had to adapt this slightly, but it was much easier to understand and modify than the other answers :)

Comment: Indeed the code was rather schematic and incomplete - the forEach could be another suggestion for adaptation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested elements and you don't know how deep is your tree/graph/whatever, you should use recursion. This is a simple pseudo-code that might help you a bit:

```
function traverseTree(tree) {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        if (tree[i].hasOwnProperty('content-kind') && tree[i]['content-kind'] === 'Video') {
            results.push(tree[i]);
        } else if (tree[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            results = results.concat(traverseTree(tree[i].children)); // here's the magic
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hannxqr/

Answer (score 0):

You could make a recursive function that loops around and around, OR you could semi-fake-badly-parse the JSON yourself:

```
json = '{"children":[{"children":[{"children":[{"content-kind":"video","foo":"bar"},{"content-kind":"video","foo":"baz"}]}]}]}';
objects = json.match(/{"content-kind":"video"[^}]+}/g);
```

`objects` will now be an array of JSON objects:

```
['{"kind":"video","foo":"bar"}', '{"kind":"video","foo":"baz"}']
```

which you can loop through, `JSON.parse()` and read.

This method will require a very precise JSON structure and key order and encoding etc.